# Datatables onchange event for input field

Tags: datatables

I have input fields in my project with a special class (date_input_field). On change these fields format the data that user has entered. The problem is that these fields work fine absolutely everywhere EXCEPT DataTables. I tried rowCallback in my datatable itself, but it didn't help. Why? And how can I fix that?

```
$(".date_input_field").change(function () {    
  ...format the data
});

var table2 = $("#stopsTable").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "/api/stops/" + confirmationId,
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  columns: [                          
    {
      data: "date1",
      render: function (data) {
        var arr = data.split("T")[0].split("-");

        return "<input class='form-control date_input_field' type='text' value='" + arr[2] + "-" + arr[1] + "-" + arr[0]+"'/>" ;}}
  ],
  order: [[0, "asc"]],
  scrollY: '50vh',
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging: false,
  rowCallback: function (row, data) {
    $(row).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".date_input_field").change(function () {
      $(this).attr("value", "01"); 
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stupid question.
I tried the code below and it works.

```
rowCallback: function (row, data) {
  $(row).css("cursor", "pointer");
  $(row).on("change", ".date_input_field", function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.val("1111111111");
  });                      
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it - perhaps you can add some notes explaining your insights, and the solution? Something that will be useful to others who may have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

when the user edits the input on the cell this will console log the edited field with its input id `rowCallback` is the function which can trigger / perform on any cell inside the datatable

```
var datatable =  $('#datatable').DataTable({
        rowCallback: function (row, data) {
                    $(row).on("change", ".edit_qty_class", function () {
                      var input = $(this);
                      input.attr('value', input.val())
                      console.log()
                      console.log($(this).attr('id'), input.val())
                    });                      
        },

       columns: [{
                  data: "id",
                  render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                   return meta.row + 1 
                  }
                },
                {
                   data: "id",
                   title:"QTY SEND",
                   render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                         var dataID = 'edit_qty_' + data.id
                         return `<input type="number" id="`+dataID+`" name="`+dataID+`" class="edit_qty_class" value="0">`
                   }
                },
})
```